# TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object in Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I am making an email scraper using Scrapy and I keep getting this error:
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Here is my Python code I am using:

```
import re
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class EmailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'EmailScraper'
    emailHistory = {}
    custom_settings = {
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False
        #  ,'DEPTH_LIMIT' : 6
    }

emailRegex = re.compile((r"([a-zA-Z0-9_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_"
                         r"{|}~-]+)*(@)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]){2,}?(\."
                         r"))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))

def __init__(self, url=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EmailSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.start_urls = [url]
    self.allowed_domains = [url.replace(
        "http://", "").replace("www.", "").replace("/", "")]
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback="parse_item", follow=True),)

def parse_item(self, response):
    emails = re.findall(EmailSpider.emailRegex, response._body)
    for email in emails:
        if email[0] in EmailSpider.emailHistory:
            continue
        else:
            EmailSpider.emailHistory[email[0]] = True
            yield {
                'site': response.url,
                'email': email[0]
            }
```

I have seen a lot of answers but I am very new to python so Im not sure how I would implement the code given into my code.

So if you don't mind could also tell me were to put the code in.

Thanks, Jude Wilson

Comment: which line is giving the error?

Comment: Try using `response.text` instead of `response.body`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response._body` is not a `str`(string object), so you cannot use `re`(regex) on it. If you look for its object type you will find out it is a `bytes`(bytes object).

```py
>>> type(response._body)
<class 'bytes'>
```

By decoding it to something like UTF-8 the problem should be solved.

```py
>>> type(response._body.decode('utf-8'))
<class 'str'>
```

Final `re` would be like this:

```py
emails = re.findall(EmailSpider.emailRegex, response._body.decode('utf-8'))
```